# React Native useEffect usage in async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to use async post-get request in useEffect hooks.
Is this a optimize solition?

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        await Axios.get("some url").then(async(res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(async(err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }, [isFocused])
```

Comment: For those who wonder about the explanation behind this, here's a good write up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use **redux-saga** and **redux-thunk**. But for this problem you can use call another function in your effect function.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            await Axios.get("some url").then(async (res) => {
                console.log(res);
            }).catch(async (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [isFocused])
```